Dynamic notifications
We already have an application written in Flutter, which is fully ready. The architecture has already been developed, the backend is written in Laravel, and push notifications are already working. The app is designed for charity and crowdfunding.
In crowdfunding, people periodically create their own applications, and the system sends these applications to other users. A push notification arrives, our melody sounds, the user understands that the application calls for action, and the push goes to the application itself.
The app is for iOS and for Android.
The development of a native plug-in module for iOS and Android is required. The photo shows the push that we need.
I tried to implement this using third-party libraries.

You have not asked a question.
